# difference between Nokogiri::XML(File.open()) and Nokogiri.parse(open())

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I tried opening xml file using both the ways, but only the latter part worked when I tried to use xpath.

eg., doc = as in title;

```
   doc.xpath('//feed/xyz'), worked only when I open the file using parse method.
```

One thing I noted was, the object when I open using XML:: is Nokogiri::XML::Document, while the latter one was Nokogiri::HTML::Document

Any comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Nokogiri.parse` parses HTML documents, while `Nokogiri::XML` expects valid XML document. it seems that when XML parsing fails, error is not raised, rather an empty XML document is generated. try `puts doc.to_s`, you'll probably see `"<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n"`

Comment: yes! thats true! Just wondering why, coz I don see any error as such in the XML doc. Opens fine in a browser.

Comment: According to the source code this isn't correct. `Nokogiri.parse` attempts to determine if a document is HTML by looking for a readable string or a `/^\s*<[^Hh>]*html/i` match at the start of the string, and if those tests fail it treats it as a XML document. Your best bet is to force parsing using `Nokogiri::XML()` for XML documents or `Nokogiri::HTML()` for HTML. In either case Xpath and CSS will still work. Check the returned doc's `errors` array for parsing errors or your xpath pattern if the pattern doesn't work.

Comment: tin man, you are rigt, my part about that parse parses HTML was wrong, which is obvious even after reading the documentation

Answer (score 3):

Nokogiri uses a simple test to determine whether a document is HTML or XML when you call the generic `Nokogiri.parse` method. I've seen it [return the wrong results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157138/nokogiri-oddness), and the best solution is to give Nokogiri a bit more help.

Instead of using `parse`, use `Nokogiri::XML('some xml string')` or `Nokogiri::HTML('some html string')` and it will always do the right thing. See [Parsing an HTML / XML Document](http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/parsing_an_html_xml_document.html).

XML, by definition, should validate. Nokogiri is helpful and will try to parse invalid XML (otherwise it couldn't parse HTML), but when it encounters bad XML it will flag the problem using the `errors` array as a wrapper. If you *know* a source for your document is reliable then you can skip checking but it's so easy you might as well do something like `doc.errors.any?` and react if it's true.

You don't say what type of XML you are trying to parse, but there's XML and then there's wanna-be XML. Your Xpath suggests you're trying to parse a feed. I've encountered so many bad XML feeds that I am not surprised you ran into errors. Nokogiri tries to be understanding about real-world conditions, but sometimes that's not enough and you have to tell Nokogiri to be more lenient when parsing. See the [options for `Nokogiri::XML`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/ParseOptions.html) to get the flags.

You also say in your comment to the selected answer, that the document opens fine in the browser. A browser is not a good measure for whether the document is valid, because browsers do not do validation, and, instead do everything they can to present *something* readable, even if it isn't actually correct. A parser, like Nokogiri, needs to be a lot more rigid when parsing because there isn't a human brain interpreting the results. Code that is extracting data from XML is not as forgiving about errors, nor should it be.